# Add ascending numbers to words in a sentence

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to add ascending numbers in order to words in a sentence with a formula?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,ArrayFormula(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1,"/"))&SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. A little shorter: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"/")&SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1))),""))` without `FLATTEN()` or `SUBSTITUTE()` and `ARRAYFORMULA()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Python.

```py
s = "He/is/playing/the/piano" 
new_s = []
for idx, word in enumerate(s.split('/')): 
  new_s.append(word+str(idx))

new_s = " ".join(new_s)
print(new_s)
```

Output: `He0 is1 playing2 the3 piano4`